# Is it possible to develop ASP.NET MVC 4 web app using SignalR on Win 7 Pro?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, iis-express

Is it possible to develop (and test of course) an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application **using SignalR with WebSockets** in Visual Studio 2012 on Win 7 Pro and IISExpress 8.0?

I read all above is not possible with the "normal" IIS (7.5) under Win 7 Pro. But how about IISExpress?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't. Refer to this document http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Comment: Thanks. And what about the SignalR fallback to long polling etc.? Would that work on win 7 pro IIS8Express or even on the "normal" IIS7.5 there?

Comment: SignalR falls back to the appropriate transport as outlined in the matrix

Comment: Thanks. Therefore nothing speaks against beginning development of a (mixed internet/intranet) mvc 4 web application using signalR on win 7 pro and when taking it in production on iis8 (i have no hoster yet..) benefit of the speedy websockets?

Comment: I did asp.net web forms for years. But til now no mvc/ef/signalr/bootstrap etc because of the "legacy system" of the company which i work for.. But now i want to learn the _new ASP.NET stuff_ on a social community project which also needs cms functionality. Security (SSL) is a concern. Beside this the web application has to be web responsive (phone/tablet/pc). I hope i choose the right technologies -> MVC 4, SignalR, Twitter Bootstrap for UI, EF5. (?)